# Printing hex-string format variable in python

Tags: python, snmp

I'm retrieving a hex-string format IP address of CDP neighboor from the router using NET-SNMP. However, I get instead something weird thing. Any help? Thank you

Comment: You need to provide more details: the code you are using and the thing  you've received.

Comment: Per [RFC 3416](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3416) I think the IPAddress an IPv4 address is stored as 4 octets. You're probably getting back a packed binary string value for the IP address. Try running the "weird thing" through `import binascii; print binascii.hexlify(weird_thing)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alecxe mentioned, you really need to provide more details when asking questions.  Fortunately, I've used the NET-SNMP bindings for Python and already know what you are talking about.

To convert the binary data you receive from the NET-SNMP bindings to a hex representation, use the Python [binascii](http://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) module.  The b2a_hex function is what you are looking for.

The following is mostly from memory, so it may not be exactly correct, but probably close enough to give you an idea.

```
import netsnmp
import binascii

session = netsnmp.Session(Community='public', DestHost='myagentip', Version=1)
vbwithbinarydata = netsnmp.VarBind('oid_to_binary_data')
varlist = netsnmp.Varlist(vbwithbinarydata)
session.get(varlist)
print binascii.b2a_hex(vbwithbinarydata.val)
```